# Documentation Request - Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, declaration

Team,

Where can I find documentation regarding the left side of the equation of the below JavaScript Code:

```
var [a, b, c] = "10-11-12".split('-');

Result:
a = 10
b = 11
c = 12
// Note: this is used in Google Apps Script
```

[image: Apps Script UI Example]

Thanks!

Comment: That is no JavaScript, at least in 1.6 and under. Run it in a browser: _SyntaxError: Unexpected token [_. Nothing like making a language act like others. Yikes.

Comment: Why is this getting voted down? This is valid in JavaScript 1.7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2fsection%29)

**NOTE** it's only available if your runtime is >= [JavaScript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=New_in_JavaScript_1.7)

Comment: @ChristopherMartin, that's not what the question is, though. The OP is simply looking for documentation regarding this new feature; OP said nothing about implementing/using it.

Comment: Just thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla Developer Network has some great documentation on the split method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: He's asking about the destructing assignment, not the `.split()` method.

Comment: @macek Where does he state that?

Comment: @TFerrell, I suppose I'm making an assumption based on the amount of help/documentation you'd get searching for "javascript split method"...

Comment: it is implied by him tagging variables declaration

Comment: You are correct Chris. Next time, however, I'll work on being more precise on what question is being asked.  : )

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly - With no offense implied or intended for propjk007, who used the right tags here, I'll eat my hat if the day ever comes that we can depend on _everybody_ to tag their questions correctly. (But yes, I too assumed the question was about the assignment syntax, since `.split()` is pretty easy to Google.)

Comment: Well yeah, that's true, but if we assume tags are incorrect then it is pointless to tag a question in the first place